# What does the condition of $T_{3\frac{1}{2}}$ space mean exactly?

Tags: general-topology, terminology, definition

> A topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is said to be $T_{3\frac{1}{2}}$
>   if given $x \in X$, and a closed set $C \subset X$, $x \not \in C,
>  \exists f:X \to [0,1]$ s.t. $f(x) = 0, f(C) = 1$

This condition seems to be a little bit arbitrary, what is the implication for a function to map a point and closed set to $0,1$?

What is an example of such a space?

Comment: Recall that $T_3$ would let you separate $x$ from $C$ using open neighbourhoods. $T_{3\frac{1}{2}}$ basically says that you can do this in a nice way, so that the separating neighbourhoods have some room between them.

Comment: I'd have chosen the equivalent condition with $f(C)=0$ and $f(x)=1$ to make it easier to see how this works in metric spaces. Then you define $f(y)=\min(1,d(C,y)/d(C,x))$, where $d(C,y)=\inf_{c\in C} d(c,y)$. The significance of $0$ and $1$ is not much, except that they should be any two real numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Tychonoff spaces are the spaces with a special relation to the reals: the are precisely the spaces we can embed into (so can see as esentially subspaces of) $\mathbb{R}^I$ for some set $I$.

They are precisely the spaces $X$ that have a compactification (a space $Y$ in which we embed $X$ as a dense subset and such that $Y$ is compact Hausdorff).

They are the natural spaces to study the ring of (real-valued) continuous functions $C(X)$ on. Etc.

So these spaces popped up so naturally, so we needed a name for it, and it's inbetween $T_3$ and $T_4$ (the latter by Urysohn's lemma, which let's us separate two closed disjoint sets in a normal space not just by open sets, but even by a continuous function).

Answer (score 2):

$T_{3\frac{1}{2}}$ spaces are also called Tychonoff spaces or completely regular. They fall between $T_3$ and $T_4$ spaces with respect to the separation axioms.  In particular, Urysohn's lemma shows that every $T_4$ space is completely regular.

It is an exercise in Folland's Real Analyis to show the following:
If $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is completely regular, then $\mathcal{T}$ is the weak topology generated by $C(X)$.

The [Moore plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_plane) is an example that is $T_{3\frac{1}{2}}$ but not $T_4$.